# Djangorestframework Dynamic api and serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

With django rest framework (see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) I want to create an api that's not based on a model but on definitions in a database.
Let's suppose I want to create an api that have some fields, convert those fields, call another (extrenal api)with the converted fields and give back those (or also converted) results in my api.
The api should be build upon the definitions in the database, the api is called with the id of this definition in the slug.

I want to build this in the djangorestframework because this has some neat things (like browsable api which is very handy for testing while developing)

I guess I need to start with the generic api view and override the get serialzer. The get serializer can use the id of the definitions in the slug.

The serializer itselve should be completely build dynamic...

Any idea how to start with this last part? (as soon as I have some working, I will post the code)

I saw this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#dynamically-modifying-fields 
But this starts with a serialzer and than modifies it (or actually only hide already defineds fields). So mine should be way more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend the default `Serializer` in DRF and override `get_fields`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this... you will probably get the credits for the answer on this question!

Comment: That's why I love DRF! In combination with init (to set the id for the definition), and get_fields I managed to do what I wanted.